# Java request - Sumo Logic

Tags: java, sumologic

I am passing the following request to the sumo logic application and receiving "unparsable query" as the output. What is the problem in this query? Am I missing some escape strings?

```
String searchJobId = sumoClient.createSearchJob(
   "_sourceCategory=na2_*_incomingaudit | parse regex \"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} (?<host>[^ ]+) (?<tenant>[^ ]+) (?<identity>[^ ]+) (?<correlation_id>[^ ]+) (?<win32ThreadId>[^ ]+) (?<elapsedtime>[^ ]+) (?<context>[^ ]+) (?<message>[^ ]+) (?<exception>[^ ]+) (?<request>[^ ]+) (?<response>[^ ]+)\" | parse regex \"app=(?<app>[^ ]+)\" | parse regex \"appv=(?<appversion>[^ ]+\") | where app in (\"ios-mobile\",\"android-mobile\") | count by tenant | where tenant<> \"-\" | sort by _count" ,        Long.toString(startTimestamp),
       Long.toString(endTimestamp),
        "UTC");
```

Note: This is updated with the below suggestions and couldn't make it work.

Comment: i'm not familiar with sumologic but i notice this section has a start quote but no end quote  `parse regex \"appv=(?<appversion>[^ ]+) `

Comment: I added double quotes and getting the same issue.

Comment: The missing end quote that @DHall found and the extra space that Dagriel found are the only two problems I see. Hopefully you tried fixing both at once? Just checking. Since those are the known issues, can you add the updated call to the post?

Comment: I have updated the request with the changes mentioned by Dhall and Dagriel @BrianStephens but still problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing quote is coming before the close of the capture group in the following parse statement of your query.

```
parse regex \"appv=(?<appversion>[^ ]+\")
```

Try to change to:

```
parse regex \"appv=(?<appversion>[^ ]+)\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space at the beggining:

```
parse regex  \"^[0-  9]{
```

Comment: Removed the extra space but getting the same response